# PHP соединение через прокси

Tags: curl, php, http, сокет, proxy

Привет всем!
Почему не коннектится? Без прокси работает. А с прокси пустой экран. В чем ошибка? Модули curl установлены.

```
 <?php
        //error_reporting(E_ALL);

        if( $ch = curl_init ())
        {            
         curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.ya.ru'); 
         curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
         curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "79.136.243.142:3128"); 
         curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5); 
         curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
         curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true); 
         curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
         $result = curl_exec($ch); 
         //print curl_errno ($ch); 
         //print $result; 
         echo $result;
         curl_close ($ch); 
        } 
 ?>
```

Comment: 79.136.243.142:3128

чето больно порт знакомый, попробуй поставить CURLPROXY_HTTP вместо   CURLPROXY_SOCKS5

Comment: выдает 7. В бразузере надо ставить в настройках адрес и порт прокси? А так все пробовал, ничего нету. Прокси с логином кстати.

Comment: Причем тут броузер ? Если с логином то еще нужно установить: CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH

Comment: Через http прокси работает. А через socks5 нет. Как так? версия PHP 5.3.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего из-за того, что прокси-сервер не socks5.
Попробуйте поставить `CURLPROXY_HTTP` вместо `CURLPROXY_SOCKS5`, если заработает, то так оно и есть.

Comment: Ну ладно, поищу socks5 прокси. А как кэшировать страницу? Мы ж до этого в переменную храниили страницу.