# Кэширующий прокси (HTTP или SOCKS5)

Tags: curl, php, http, сокет, proxy

Привет всем.

[Предыдущий вопрос с использованием прокси HTTP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/112853/php-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8).
Теперь!
Как сохранить содержимое страницы? Т.е. кэшировать страницы и хранить их в папку.
Нашел в инете функцию:

> `CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE  TRUE` для использования глобального кэша DNS. Этот параметр не является потокобезопасным и по умолчанию включен.

Вот с этой функцией как работать?

Еще нашел:

> Note that if you want to use a proxy and use it as a *cache*, you'll have to do:
>   
>    else by default Curl puts a "Pragma: no-cache" header in and thus force cache misses for all requests.

Пример функции, может, это не относится, но все же приведу.

```
 // Определить папку для хранения кэшированных данных 
    define ('CACHE_DIR',dirname(__FILE__).'/cache'); 
 // Запись данных в кэш 
 function save_cache($file, $data) { 
    if ($f=fopen(CACHE_DIR.'/'.$file,'w')) { 
        fwrite($f,serialize($data)); 
        fclose($f); 
        return true; 
    } 
    else { 
        return false; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Вопрос закрыт!

Answer (score 2):

Вы мешаете мух с котлетами, да еще и тараканов в общую кучу добавляете.

во первых по поводу: **CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE** Любое доменное имя (тобишь адресс) переводится в ip адресс, так вот, что бы не делать постоянно nslookup эти данные кешируются, например запоминается что для google.com ip адресс - 173.194.35.37 к странице это никакого отношения не имеет!

Во вторых, кеширующий прокси -это кеширующий прокси и php тут не причем. Вы делаете просто запрос на страницу через кеширующий прокси сервер, а он уже сам выполянет операции кеширования.

Тот код что вы привели - это попытка сделать кеширование самостоятельно. Вроде нормально, только я бы сделал немного по другому, что то типа (псевдокод):

```
function getPage($page) {
    if (есть файлик $page в кеше) {
        return file_get_contents(CACHE.'/'.$page);
    }
    $content = curlGetPage($page);
    saveToCache($page, $content);
    return $content;

}
```

тобишь функиция getPage проверяет кеш, если тсриници в кеше нету то грузит через курл и сохраняет в кеш, при следующем таком же запросе страница возьмется из кеша.

А вообще вопрос достаточно абстрактный и туманный. Так что я затрудняюсь дать вменяемый ответ

Comment: Функцию savetocache откуда взяли? С моего примера?

Comment: это псевдокод, тобишь только разяснение порядка действий.

но в общем случае ваша функкия вполне подойдёт

Comment: аа понятно с псевдокодом